# Loading set of SVG symbols in SVG marker option

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology, features, svg

I have a folder full of SVG symbols for my project. how can I add them to SVG path. Because now I can only call one symbol at a time. but I want to use those symbols as marker, categorized ways and all other possible ways that can make my work easier.

Answer (score 7):

Go to "Settings" > "User Profiles" > "Open Active Profile Folder".

Create an `svg` directory here and paste in this folder all your svg (you can create folders in subfolders to organize).

Then, you will find your SVG in "User Symbols" when choosing SVG Markers (see below screenshot)

[image]

You may also use the "QGIS resource sharing" plugin e.g as it enables sharing resources including svg e.g https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/usage/installing-collection.html

Answer (score 7):

To complete @ThomasG77 answer there is another place to set the path to SVG folder (usefull if you dont want to put your SVG in your user profile folder.

Got to "Settings" > "Options..." then select the System tab, here there you can define the path to your SVG folder (You may add as many SVG folder as you need or use a general folder with subfolder, in this case the subfolder organisation will be displayed in the symbol selector). To add a folder click on the + sign on the top right and navigate to your SVG folder.

In the below picture you can see that I have added an "SVG_QGIS" folder at the root of the H network drive (on your installation it will show the defaults SVG folders locations that came with QGIS or those that may have been added by plugins)

[image]

Comment: Forgot this one. Thanks for the addition